# Agrupar elementos de un List<> con igual valor C# - LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo un List<> de elementos que obtengo al leer nodos de un xml, en algunos casos estos nodos (elementos) tienen el mismo nombre, he intentado agruparlos usando LinQ

Este método **Distinct** me retorna todos los elementos de mi List <> que tienen atributo **Name** tambien he usado el método **GroupBy**, pero mi idea es agrupar solamente los elementos con el mismo nombre.

```
public static void Generatefields(XDocument xmlElement )
        {
            List<XElement> raicesCap = GetRaicesCaptura(xmlElement.Root);
            foreach (var raiz in raicesCap)
            {

                var capturaElems = GetCapturaElements(raiz);
                
                var result = capturaElems.DistinctBy(X => X.Name)// uso este método para agrupar;

             }
        }

// También usé este método, pero con el mismo resultado :(

var result = from item in capturaElems
              group item by item.Name into g
              select new CapturaElement() {
                 Name = g.Key,
                 
              };



//Mi clase 
public class CapturaElement
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [XmlElement("complexType")]
        public ComplexType ComplexType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Mejora la pregunta agregando más detalles y un ejemplo mínimo verificable :D

Comment: Vale... los elementos de la lista los obtengo de 3 raices principales , estas raices o nodos padres cada una tiene en su interior dichos elementos o campos los cuales son los que quiero agrupar

Comment: Creo que no me dejé entender, revisa este enlace por favor :D https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: En esta linea guardo los elementos en la variable capturaElems por medio de un metodo propio : var capturaElems = GetCapturaElements(raiz);

Comment: En cada raiz pueden haber elementos con nombres iguales entonces no se como agruparlos ya que las raices las recorro por medio del foreach

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]podrías probar con:

```
var Duplicados = raicesCap.GroupBy(x => x.Name).SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1));
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, así me esta retornado lo mismo, pero "skipea" el primer elemento, debo decir que  mi intención es agrupar los que tienen mismo nombre, osea el mismo valor en el atributo Name, saludos¡